# Can I configure Logstash to use an index which includes a parameterized date?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm implementing Logstash/Kibana/ElasticSearch to provide a quick dashboard for looking into our Apache logs.  So far I've created a single index which has the logs appended to it, but I'm now looking to partition the index so that there is one index per day.

Currently I'm importing logs via a daily job:

```
cat logfile.txt | /opt/logstash/bin/logstash --config apacheimport.conf
```

The config's `output` section specifies the index:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    ...
    index => "apache"
    ...
  }
}
```

How would I configure it to use a specified date (the date needs to be parameterized, the logs are never from the current day and the import can be for a time-range in the past).

Alternatively, I'm just learning about ElasticSearch's aliasing system.  Is there is a solution where Logstash always writes to an `apache` alias and elasticsearch internally determines the correct index?  Any references or hints if this is possible or not would be great in evaluating it as another option.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there's any way to pass it on the command line, but you could do something like:

```
filter { 
  ruby {
    code => 'event["file"] = ENV["SOME_ENV_VAR_NAME"]'
  }
}
```

And then you could write a wrapper script that sets/exports that `SOME_ENV_VAR_NAME` and calls logstash.